# dateTime's struggle in php, how to check it when is passed as String

Tags: php, datetime, symfony

I've a varible passed as String on a php method in a Symofny2 Application:

```
public function eventAllByScenarioAndDateAction($apiVersion, $scenario,$date, $options)
```

then the `$date` must be a DateTime type in format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` to passing it for populating a table by using a sql query.

I'd like to check if the format passed is correct so i put the control:

```
$dateControl1=strtotime($date);
```

and then the if sentence:

```
if ($dateControl1 === false)
```

but the "if" is setted to false just if I send something like `2013-33-01` and not for example if i cut the `HH:MM:SS`

so how can I check how the $date is passed to the method and for example having different behavior if I have only `YYYY-MM-DD` (but correct) or the whole `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Again, how can I discard format different from the expected one (for example with / instead of - etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to be that specific. The following works just fine:

```
$foo = new DateTime("2013-01-01");
$bar = new DateTime("2013-01-01 01:23:45");
echo $foo->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // 2013-01-01 00:00:00
echo $bar->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //2013-01-01 01:23:45
```

If an invalid date is your main concern, us a try/catch clause:

```
try {
    $baz = new DateTime("foobar");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // do something else here
    // like throwing an HTTP Exception
}
```

Comment: to me same problem of the above reply... how can I implement something like:`if(YYYY-MM-DD) do something OR if(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) do somenthing else`

Comment: @JahStation The point is, you don't need to check if the string is valid. Wrap it in a try/catch clause and your done!

Comment: yes @nietofir it make sense, so something like this could works: `try {
    $dateNew = new DateTime('$date');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}`

Comment: @JahStation Works perfectly, I'm getting an exception with that time string (that is - by definition - catchable): `Warning: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2013-22-22) at position 6 (2): Unexpected character' in php shell code:1`

Comment: yes same exception to me...but is catched by symfony before the catch clause.

Comment: @JahStation that can't be. Would you mind sharing that specific function/class in your question?

Comment: Hi sorry for my delay...the exception was catched by Symofony2 framework...so actually your soluction workin fine for me, by forcing symfony to bypass the caputre exception....

Answer (score 0):

Actually the @nietonfir solution works fine for me:

```
try { $dateNew = new \DateTime('$date'); } catch (\Exception $e) { echo return $e;  }
```

(note the "\" before some declaration for bypassing symofny exception)
Because if someone passing just YYYY-mm-dd the date is completed by 00:00:00 hour 
But what I'd like to do is to checkin what is $date before validate it!

So for example

```
SOMETHING THAT CHECKIN DATE IF ITS yyyy-mm-dd `hh:mm:ss OR just yyyy-mm-dd
and THEN IF WE ARE IN THE SECOND CASE DOING SOMETHING BEFORE doing

try { $dateNew = new \DateTime('$date'); } catch (\Exception $e) { echo return $e;  }
```

Approach like:

```
list($date1, $time) = explode("  ",$date);
```

doesn't works because the space "  " isn't recognized if we are in yyyy-mm-dd case and it raise an exception like:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in...........
```